# Silverlight/WPF parenthetical value syntax in a Storyboard animation

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, storyboard

Somehow in my WPF studies, this detail has escaped me.

I've seen syntax of this sort:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" ... >
...
```

Why is the StoryBoard.TargetProperty *value* surrounded by parentheses?  What does that mean?  Clearly it means something, because my code doesn't work without it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax for binding to an attached property on a class: [(Class.Property)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6e01088f-e145-4dc5-8c08-d053ac33a673/)

You can read more about Dependency Properties and Attached Properties [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html).

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx):

> This syntax is generally used for one
>   of the following cases:
>
> - The path is specified in XAML that is    in a style or template that does
>     not    have a specified Target Type. A
>     qualified usage is generally not
>     valid for cases other than this,
>     because in non-style, non-template
>     cases, the property exists on an
>     instance, not a type.
> - The property is an attached property.
> - You are binding to a static property.
>
> For use as storyboard target, the
>   property specified as propertyName
>   must be a DependencyProperty.